# Using Standard WF activities to access a web service - how to set 'expected namespace'?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation, wcf-binding

I am attempting to connect to a .Net 1.0 web service using standard activities in WF 4.0.

I am using the `SendandReceiveReplyFactory` - the send portion seems to be working - however the `ReceiveReplyForSend` is for some reason expecting a tempuri.org namespace response rather than the www.thermo.com/informatics/xmlns/limswebservice namespace.
Could anyone instruct me on how I can cause the activity to expect the correct NS.

Thanks in advance for your help.

All the best,

DJ

Error Message:

> Workflow Console: Starting Workflow... Send Done Workflow
>   3fdc4d67-dcac-4092-b34b-9c347acdfe22 Terminated. Exception:
>   System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException Error in deserializing body
>   of reply message for operation 'Process'. OperationFormatter
>   encountered an invalid Message body. Expected to find node type
>   'Element' with name 'ProcessResponse' and namespace
>   'http://tempuri.org/'. Found node type 'Element' with name
>   'ProcessResponse' and namespace
>   'http://www.thermo.com/informatics/xmlns/limswebservice' Workflow
>   Console: Workflow Completed

Comment: After recieving the status badge 'tumbleweed' managed to find this excellent if equally obscure post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902388/wf4-how-to-consume-external-web-service. It seems in order to specify the namespace you use the syntax {http://someserver.org/test/}FileService

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to specify the namespace in the ServiceContractName Property of the 'Send' Activity using the following syntax '{http://someserver.org/test/}FileService ' in my case '{http://www.thermo.com/informatics/xmlns/limswebservice}LIMSSoap' . The syntax was sensitive to the trailing slash so a little trial and error was needed.
Many thanks to the contributors to [WF4 - How to consume external web service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902388/wf4-how-to-consume-external-web-service) for the answer.